# Efficient way to read JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

I have seen different method to read JSON files from localy in Nodejs. like this;

1. Method

   **using fs library**

   Sync

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8'));
   ```

   Async:

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var obj;
   fs.readFile('file', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;
     obj = JSON.parse(data);
   });
   ```

   Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011078/7724032
2. Method

   **using require()**

   ```
   let data = require('/path/file.json');
   ```
3. Method

   using Ajax request
   [How to retrieve data from JSON file using Jquery and ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34179986/7724032)

There might have any other ways. But I heard when reading JSON file using Method 1 is efficient than other methods.

I'm developing a module where I have to read a JSON file when each client side request and Im currently using Method 1. This is banking application and performance is matter. so help me to find which way is good to use this senario?

Thanks , Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you don't need fs, and you want it synchronous, using require is most efficient because it saves you memory. If you don't need fs and you want it async, using xmlHttpRequest is most efficient. If you need fs for other things, fs is the most efficient method in either case because once loaded it's faster than require and it has lower time cost than xmlHttpRequest

Comment: @Asthmatic Great & Thanks ! This answer will be helpful lot. :)

Comment: If you're dealing with a large JSON, by far the greatest bottleneck will be `JSON.parse` itself. It requires that you load the whole file in a `String` (plus, JavaScript uses UTF16 so double the memory usage) and blind JSON parsing is quite slow. If your input is an array or dictionary you can 1) stream the JSON parsing so you can start working before you've loaded the whole file, 2) filter while parsing so you only generate the objects you want.

Answer (score 2):

Method 3) is out of consideration as it combines one of the other methods with a network request, so you still have to choose one of the other methods.

I assume that Method 2) is leaking memory. NodeJS will return exactly the same thing by reference if you require it twice:

```
 require("thing") === require("thing")
```

therefore if you require something once, it will stay in memory forever. This is fast if you look it up multiple times, but if you got a lot of files, it will fill up memory.

Now only Method 1) is left, and there I would go with the async version, as it can perform multiple requests in parallel, which will outperform the sync method if your server is under load.

---

I personally would go with option 4):

Store it in a database. Databases load the data into memory for faster access, and they were built to handle a lot of files. As you are dealing with JSON, Mongodb would be a good choice:

```
 const db = mongodb.collection("json");

 function getFile() {
    return db.findOne({ "name": "test" });
 }
```

Comment: This is a far better answer. @Jonas Wilms

Answer (score 0):

so I created a big json file and measured time to see which one is faster, the code to create the file is at the end and commented.

```
const fs = require('fs')

// method 1 - sync
console.time('method_1_sync ')
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf8'))
console.log(obj[1000] === 2000)
console.timeEnd('method_1_sync ')

// method 2
console.time('method_2      ')
let data = require('./file.json')
console.log(data[1000] === 2000)
console.timeEnd('method_2      ')

// method 1 - aysnc
console.time('method_1_async')
fs.readFile('file.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(data[1000] === 2000)
  console.timeEnd('method_1_async')
})

/*
var obj = {}

for (i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
  obj[i] = i+i
}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj)
fs.writeFile('file.json', json, function() {})
*/
```

Here's the result on my machine:

```
method_1_sync : 131.861ms
method_2      : 131.510ms
method_1_async: 130.521ms
```

`method_1_async` seems to be the fastest. Method 3 is not worth testing because of network latency.

Comment: This is a very bad test case without any meaning. you should run the whole thing a few thousand times and measure the average time.

Comment: You should add another test case where you put the JSON file into a DB stored in memory and see what the query times are.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question and added benchmark for comparing require vs readFile vs readFileSync [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59980912/1727132).